# launchctl slow on ssh to OS X server

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, login, launchctl, osx-leopard

I'm running an OS X 10.5.8 server. When my users ssh into it, it can take up to about 10 seconds before they see a prompt.

I've turned on debug for ssh and see it's pausing at the "Entering interactive session", looking at the server at this point, the "launchctl" process is running for the user that just logged in.

So, can I track this down further as to why launchctl is taking about 10 seconds to start up before the ssh prompt comes back? I'm assuming it's trying to start up per-user launch daemons and agents?

Is it a known problem that launchctl is so slow? (This is especially irritating because we use the "git" scm tool over ssh!)  Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Thanks for any help or advice.

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this page, where it is explained which settings to change in the SSH configuration files to make SSH on OS X faster:

http://maestric.com/doc/mac/fix_ssh_connection_delays

Hope this helps!